# functor generation from member function pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I am trying to simplify (via `make_fn()`) the generation of functors that preprocess parameters (via `wrap()`) for member functions of arity *n*.
Generating the functors is basically working, but until now only by explicitly specifying the parameter types for the member function.
Now i'd like to generate the correct functor from the member function type it handles:

```
struct X {};

template<class C, typename T1, bool (C::*F)(T1)>
inline // there are more for T1..TN
bool wrap(C* c, X x) 
{
    return (c->*F)(process<T1>(x));
}

template<class C, typename T1, bool (C::*F)(T1)> 
inline // there are more for T1..TN
boost::function<bool (C*, X)> make_fn(F f) // <- problem here, F is not a type
{
    return boost::bind(&wrap<C, T1, F>, _1, _2);
}
```

With this however, vc++ and g++ don't see `F` as a type for the parameter of `make_fn()`. I must miss something obvious here and am feeling somewhat blind.

The idea was that it should work like this:

```
struct A 
{
    bool f1(bool) { return true; }
};

void test()
{
    A a;
    X x;
    make_fn(&A::f1)(&a, x);
}
```

Any ideas on how to make that work?

*Background:*
I have a fixed interface which, when simplified, looks like this:

```
bool invoke(C* c, const char* const functionName, int argCount, X* args);
```

X is a variant type which i have to convert to certain backend types (int, std::string, ...).
To handle these calls i have a map of functors that are looked up by name and map these calls to member functions of some instance.
The intention of the wrapping is to avoid manual conversions and instead generate functors which do the conversion for me or `throw`. I have this working with a macro based solution, but that solution requires to specify the types and the parameter count explicitly.
Via function overload resolution i hope to generate the correct converting functor implicitly from the member function signature.

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to achieve? What is it that you want to simplify from bind (boost/c++0x)? It seems as if what you want is a template that takes a single argument that is a member function pointer and creates a functor that requires an instance and the appropriate number of arguments without user intervention (that is, without the user making the argument number/type explicit, is that so?

Comment: Yes, basically i want a functor with a fixed number of argument that wraps member functions of arity n and with arbitrary types.

Comment: It looks to me that you want template deduction for a non-type parameter. F is not a type: it is a pointer to a particular member function, hence you cannot do `make_fn(F f)`. I'm not sure if it is going to work out: it seems that you want to construct a template from a runtime member-function-pointer variable.

Comment: But a member function has a type/signature and i should be able to deduct from that too?  The deduction should happen at compile time.
Boost bind seems to do similar things, but as to their extensive implementation details i can't see how they solved that.

Comment: Does boost actually use non-type template parameters? Imagine: `bool (X::*mp)(Y) = rand() % 2 ? &X::foo : &X::bar; make_fn(mp);` What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'll rename your X to T. I expect that i get one functor that calls "wrap<T,Y,bool (T::*mp)(Y)>(T* t,X x) { return (t->*mp)(process<Y>(x)); }. .... Btw, how do you do in-comment markup?

Comment: And... i could not figure out how exactly boost works in that regard, so i am not sure. If F is not a type - then what is the type of F?

Comment: The type of F is `bool (C::*)(T1)`. As far as I can see, you could expect wrap<T, Y, &T::foo> or wrap<T, Y, &T::bar>, but how could the same statement produce a different type from a runtime value?

Comment: But that type of F is unnamed, how do i access it? As a sidenote, i don't expect dynamic types, i just don't want to write things like "wrap<T,Y,&T::foo>" explicitly or via a macro a la FUNCTION_1(T,&T::foo,Y) when it is known statically. The explicit usage works by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that you are attempting to turn a pointer passed to a function into a non-type template argument, which I'm afraid is not going to work (see comments to your question).

What you could do, is to store the function pointer in a function object. The following appears to compile:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct X {};

template <class T>
bool process(X) { return true; }


template <class C, class T1, class Func>
struct wrap1
{
    typedef bool result_type;
    Func f;

    wrap1(Func f): f(f) {}

    bool operator()(C* c, X x)
    {
        return (c->*f)(process<T1>(x));
    }
};

template<class C, typename T1>
inline // there are more for T1..TN
boost::function<bool (C*, X)> make_fn(bool (C::*f)(T1))
{
    return boost::bind(wrap1<C, T1, bool (C::*)(T1)>(f), _1, _2);
}


struct A
{
    bool f1(bool) { return true; }
};

void test()
{
    A a;
    X x;
    make_fn(&A::f1)(&a, x);
}
```

However, I'm not sure if that is any good and how you would create the rest of the wrappers. For the latter you might just get a compiler that supports variadic templates. :)

Comment: Although i had hoped to avoid generating another functor, this is working - thanks :) For the pseudo-variadic templates (i need it in vc8) make_fn() can be defined for all needed arities.